# Javascript ++ vs +=1

Tags: javascript

```
var a = "ab";
var b = "ab";
a+=1; // "ab1"
b++; // "NaN"
```

(Tested on chrome's V8)

Can someone explain why the results are different based on the internal atomic actions of the `++` arithmetic operator and the `+=` assignment operator with argument `1`

Comment: Try `a = '12';`, and try `++`, `--`, `+=1` and `-=1`. JavaScript is fun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`++` converts to number, and then increments, `+=` with a String concatenates.

From the spec:

> 11.3.1 Postfix Increment Operator
>
> ...
>     3. Let `oldValue` be `ToNumber(GetValue(lhs))`.
>     4. Let `newValue` be the result of adding the value 1 to `oldValue`, using the same rules as for the `+` operator (see 11.6.3).

For the `a+=1` case, if you add a number to a string or the other way around the number gets converted to a string:

> 11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )
>
> ...
>     7. If `Type(lprim)` is String or `Type(rprim)` is String, then
>         a. **Return** the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)
>
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim).

Comment: This only covers half the question, you should also note that in the `+=1` case `1` is converted *to a string* for the concatenation.

Answer (score 10):

- `++` tries to increment a *Number* (if it's not a number, this will fail - resulting in `NaN`)
- `+=` is concatenation, in this case the JavaScript engine figures out that one side is a string, so they're both concatenated *as strings*.

They're different because they're different operations, `++` is specifically an [arithmetic operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators), where as `+=` is a more general [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) that behaves differently based on the data type - specifically, [string has its own implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators).

Comment: You would think `++` & `+=1` are logically equivelant. I guess I forgot `+` is overloaded for String & Number

Comment: @Raynos -  yup, well string overloads `+` and `+=` anyway, but it's more that `++` is specific to number here :)

Comment: @nick: I am really curious about you, cause i really see you answering the questions 24/7 which is really good :D to help people wish i could do this, But i really want to know do you sleep !? and do you have a job ? :D

Comment: @Raynos, @Nick Craver: I think the equivalent to `x += 1` is `++x`, not `x++`.

Comment: @Omeid - Check my activity log, I was off after around 7am yesterday morning ;) It just seems otherwise since you're likely on the same times as I am :)

Comment: @elusive - It's just a matter of when you're *checking* the value, they both have the same effect on `x`.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Right, but this can be very important when using it in expressions (because of that). I prefer the `x += 1` version, however.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the + operator in javascript is both the mathematical + and the string concatenation operator, while the ++ is always a mathematical operator.

So, when you have:

`string = string + number;`

the number is converted to string and concatenated to the first string.

When you have

`string++`

you will convert the string to a number, getting NaN, and then add one to that - getting still, NaN.